# Como soluciono el error al iniciar el servidor Rails de mi aplicación?

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mvc, servidor

Seguí la guía [oficial](http://rubyonrails.org.es/instala.html) de Rails para instalarlo en GNU/Linux. Durante la instalación no apareció nada fuera de lo normal, pero luego de crear la aplicación, al querer ejecutar el servidor sucede lo siguiente:

```
carlos@carlos-NE56R ~/aplicacion $ bin/rails server
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.8.2 (ruby 2.4.0-p0), codename: Sassy Salamander
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Exiting
/home/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/binder.rb:249:in `gethostbyname': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)
    from /home/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/binder.rb:249:in `localhost_addresses'
    from /home/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/binder.rb:262:in `add_tcp_listener'
    from /home/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/binder.rb:105:in `block in parse'
    from /home/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/binder.rb:88:in `each'
    from /home/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/binder.rb:88:in `parse'
    from /home/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/runner.rb:144:in `load_and_bind'
    from /home/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/single.rb:87:in `run'
    from /home/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/launcher.rb:172:in `run'
    from /home/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:64:in `run'
    from /home/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:296:in `start'
    from /home/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:79:in `start'
    from /home/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in server'
    from /home/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
    from /home/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
    from /home/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /home/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/carlos/aplicacion/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /home/carlos/aplicacion/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /home/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /home/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    from /home/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/carlos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/carlos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/carlos/aplicacion/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
carlos@carlos-NE56R ~/aplicacion $
```

**Como puedo solucionar este error?**

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puedes dar un poco mas de información? aparte de seguir esa guia de instalación que mas hiciste? si ejecutas en la consola `host localhost` que te sale? revisa que tengas todo bien en el fichero `/etc/hosts`

Comment: @Jhd Si ejecuto `host localhost` en la consola, aparece primero `;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`. Luego de tirar un `ping` a `www.google.com` (y de tener respuesta), al ejecutar nuevamente `host localhost`, recibo como respuesta `Host localhost not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`. Como se si tengo bien el fichero /etc/hosts? Gracias.

Comment: Que tienes en el fichero `/etc/hosts` ? deberías tener algo como

`127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost`
`::1  localhost.localdomain localhost`

Comment: @Jhd Antes tenia `127.0.0.1 carlos-NE56R # added by Apache Friends XAMPP` y ahora **le agregue** `127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost::1 localhost.localdomain localhost` **y el servidor ya funciona**. Solo por curiosidad: Fue *culpa* del XAMPP, otro programa o por defecto ya viene así en mi sistema? (Utilizo Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon 64-bit, basado en Ubuntu 14.04) Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Ese error ocurre cuando tienes algo mal en el fichero `/etc/hosts` por ejemplo un hostname que no puede resolver a una ip o apunta a un hostname que no existe, no te sabría decir si fue culpa de XAMPP ya que no lo uso, pero viendo el mensaje comentado que dice  `# added by Apache Friends XAMPP` puede que si

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solución:**

```
#/etc/hosts

127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain localhost
::1         localhost.localdomain localhost
```